# can't install ZIP archive management extension for PHP on centos 7

Tags: php, centos7, php-extension, php-8

**Selected PHP 8.0**

This is the message I get, but doesn't install...

Loaded plugins: copr, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- base: mirror.telepoint.bg
- epel: mirrors.ukfast.co.uk
- extras: mirror.telepoint.bg
- updates: mirror.telepoint.bg
  Package lsphp80-common-8.0.5-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
  Nothing to do
  PHP Extension Installed.

Comment: Your error message says that lsphp80 is already installed. But you're trying to install .zip right? So either find the correct php package or use pecl

Comment: Tried using pecl - but states no command found...

Comment: You need to install pecl first `yum install php-pear
`  https://electrictoolbox.com/install-php-pecl-centos/

Comment: What exactly did you run that gave you that output?